# how to work with many routes followed?

Tags: node.js

how to work with many routes followed ?

example:

```
animals1, animals2, animals3
```

for each page need to create a route ?

Do I not can make render on the same file route  ?

example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('animals1', {
        title: 'Link Idiomas',
        user: req.session.user
    });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('animals2', {
        title: 'Link Idiomas',
        user: req.session.user

    });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('animals3', {
        title: 'Link Idiomas',
        user: req.session.user

    });
});
```

Comment: Did my answer help you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create a route for each page, yes. You can render the same file on two different routes and just pass it different info. mayb you should use route params? 
For example:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('animals' + req.params.id, {
        title: 'Link Idiomas',
        user: req.session.user
    });
});
```